# 'Condtions hell' in node js

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, express

I have two layers in my application(express), first is module with function which is handling database queries, fs , and so on. Second is handling requests(also known as controller/route). I just tired of all this conditions.

**Sample code:**

```
    exports.updateImage = function(image, userId, callback) {
  fs.readFile(image.path, function (err, imageBinary) {
    if (err) callback(err);
    else {
      pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
        done();
        if (err) callback(err);
        else {
          client.query('UPDATE images SET data=$1, filesize=$2, filename=$3 WHERE user_id=$4', [imageBinary, image.size, image.originalFilename, userId], function(err) {
            if (err) callback(err);
            else callback(null);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

As you can see, I callback all my errors to my controller, then it handled as internal server error. I handle database, file system possible errors, and there is too much repetitions in my code. I suppose it is bad design, and it hard to support in production. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "tired of all these conditions" I assume you're talking about all the nested callbacks and the "march off the right side of the screen" that results from that kind of directly nested callbacks? If I'm assuming incorrectly please clarify your question and I'll delete everything I'm about to write as not related. :-)

One cheap way to avoid the `else` structure is to instead of doing

```
if(err) callback(err); 
else { ... stuff ... }
```

is to do this:

```
if(err) return callback(err);
```

Note the return: that causes execution of your function to end, nobody cares about the return values from a callback so they just get ignored. So that potentially gets rid of a layer of braces and elses.

To handle this better in general, you'll want to look at some sort of async helpers. There's three general categories of these things:

1. Helper libraries that manage the sequencing of multiple callbacks,
2. Promises, which let you represent async operations as objects, or
3. Language support to hide the details.

Examples of the three different types of libraries include [step](https://github.com/creationix/step), [flow](https://github.com/willconant/flow-js), or [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) as helper libraries, for promises there's [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when), and for language support look at [streamline](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs).

For more details, I did a presentation on exactly this topic about a year ago; the [slides are here](https://github.com/christav/embracing-async) are there's [a recording of the presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Patterns-Practices-Symposium-Online/pattern-practices-symposium-2013/Embracing-Async-Programming) as well.

Comment: Forget trying to massage your callbacks into a more workable shape, it's futile. Promises like the Q library implements are the way to tame this. It also makes trapping errors a lot more like catching exceptions, vastly simplifying the branching. The [`Q.all()`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) method alone is worth using promises and the same facility is available in other places, like Ember's RSVP system.

Comment: Thank you, nice approach, but I handle 3 or 5 types of errors, and each time I am doing it, I should write this boilerplate code, it is the main problem. But it is also useful materials. I should explain it better in my question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to need a better explanation - it's not obvious from your original question what the "boilerplate code" is that you're concerned with.

Comment: @tadman I disagree. You can make any asynchronous code fine just by naming functions and composing them afterward. If you need more, the async library is your friend. Promises are fine, but largely unnecessary in well crafted code. https://npmjs.org/package/async